# How do I iterate over a foreach in a Laravel controller and pass that to a view?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to build a simple idea tracking/commenting system, and on the summary view page I want a little detail about each post. Currently the posts and replies both live in one `posts` table, with a `newtopic` boolean to designate top-level posts and a nullable `replyto` to designate comments.

So I have my controller for the summary page like so:

```
public function index()
{
    $ideas = DB::table('posts')->addSelect(DB::raw('*,posts.created_at as pca'))
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.uid')
    ->where('newtopic','1')->orderBy('posts.id','desc')->get();
    return view('ideas.home', ['ideas' => $ideas]);
}
```

That works well enough, but I'd also like to pull, at least, the comment count and vote count and pass that summary info on to the view. I can't see a good way to do it at the controller level as the `@foreach` doesn't hit until it gets to the view. I'm still fairly new to laravel and the MVC pattern in general, is there a subcontroller/subview type thing I need to do to get the desired result?

home.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    @foreach($ideas as $idea)
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="{{ 'ideas/'.$idea->id }}">{{ $idea->subject }}</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ $idea->content }}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Posted by {{ $idea->username }} on {{ $idea->pca }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @endforeach
@stop
```

Answer (score 2):

give this a shot maybe you will get the results you want.

```
$data = Idea::with('users','comments') -> where('newtopic',1) -> orderBy('id','DESC') -> get();
```

in your view you would iterate like you did,

```
@foreach($ideas as $idea)
  $idea -> user -> username;
  $idea -> comment -> count;
  $idea -> content; 
  $idea -> ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to go back and create some models then. Useful template to work from though.

Answer (score 1):

after `->get()` use `->toArray()` you will have the array to iterate over.

Comment: @mdamia yes but why you asking me ?

Comment: I meant to ask the OP. my bad